# DHCP server inside a virtual machine can't see other machines

Tags: linux, networking, unix, virtual-machine, dhcp

I setup a private network from virtual machines and one of the machines is the DHCP server for the group.  I want to specify a next-server for the DHCP server but I'm having trouble connecting to any of the machines that I lease IPs to.  I'm just trying to do a simple ping/ssh to 10.0.0.252 (a machine with a lease) but it doesn't seem to respond.  Any advice? I'm assuming I need to be able to connect to my next-server but maybe I'm wrong. Thanks.

Comment: in which network mode is your virtual machine operating? bridged? nat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Did machine get the address or not and is it 10.0.0.252.
2. Did machine received a ping? You can check by tcpdump/wireshark/... on client if the ping arrived. If not than the problem is somewhere in between. If yes continue.
3. Did machine sent a pong? Again - tcpdump/wireshare/... are your friends. If no than it was configured to not respond to ping. If yes - continue.
4. Did server received a ping? No additional points for guessing tools. If yes than check your firewall. If no than problem is in between.